# Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit not seeing my 8 GB RAM

Tags: ubuntu, 32-bit, pae

I have Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit with PAE enable.

```
Linux alptugay-MS-7693 3.2.0-39-generic-pae #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 27 22:25:11 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

I have been using my computer with 4 GB of ram. The output of `free -m` shows

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3995       1536       2458          0         75        484
```

I have now added another 4 GB ram. Which is identical to the other ram. But Ubuntu doesn't see it. The output of free did not change. But my bios sees 8GB ram. Also the output of `lshw` shows my 8 GB rams:

```
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 27
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 8GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
         product: Array1_PartNumber0
         vendor: A1_Manufacturer0
         physical id: 0
         serial: A1_SerNum0
         slot: A1_DIMM0
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Array1_PartNumber1
         vendor: A1_Manufacturer1
         physical id: 1
         serial: A1_SerNum1
         slot: A1_DIMM1
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
         product: Array1_PartNumber2
         vendor: A1_Manufacturer2
         physical id: 2
         serial: A1_SerNum2
         slot: A1_DIMM2
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Array1_PartNumber3
         vendor: A1_Manufacturer3
         physical id: 3
         serial: A1_SerNum3
         slot: A1_DIMM3
```

And this is the output of `dmidecode`

```
Handle 0x0027, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0013F0003FF
    Range Size: 5104 MB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0027
    Partition Width: 255

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0027
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1_DIMM0
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer0
    Serial Number: A1_SerNum0
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: Array1_PartNumber0
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: 933 MHz

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0029
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0028
    Partition Row Position: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Interleave Position: Unknown
    Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0027
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1_DIMM1
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer1
    Serial Number: A1_SerNum1
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: Array1_PartNumber1
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 126, 35 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0027
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1_DIMM2
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer2
    Serial Number: A1_SerNum2
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum2
    Part Number: Array1_PartNumber2
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: 933 MHz

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000000003FF
    Range Size: 1 kB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x002D
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0028
    Partition Row Position: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Interleave Position: Unknown
    Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0027
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: A1_DIMM3
    Bank Locator: A1_BANK3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer3
    Serial Number: A1_SerNum3
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum3
    Part Number: Array1_PartNumber3
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 126, 35 bytes
Inactive
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Check the BIOS for a memory hole/mapping setting; this may be causing this, although a cutoff at 3.1 GB is more usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the ram slots worked.